# NetworkStream.Read() not correctly reading after first iteration of loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having a problem where my code works as expected when I'm stepping through it but will read incorrect data when running normally. I thought the problem could have been timing however `NetworkStream.Read()` should be blocking and I also tested this by putting the thread to sleep for *1000ms* (more than enough time and more time than I was giving whilst stepping through).

The purpose of the code (and what is does when stepping through) is to read a bitmap image into a buffer that is preceded by a string containing the image size in bytes followed by a carriage return and a new line. I believe the problem lies in the read statements, but I can't be sure. The following code is contained within a larger loop also containing Telnet reads, however I have not has a problem with those and they are only reading ASCII strings, no binary data.

```
List<byte> len = new List<byte>();
byte[] b = new byte[2];
while (!Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b).Equals("\r\n"))
{
    len.Add(b[0]);
    b[0] = b[1];
    b[1] = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
}
len = len.FindAll(x => x != 0);
len.Add((byte)0);
string lenStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(len.ToArray());
int imageSize = int.Parse(lenStr);
byte[] imageIn = new byte[imageSize];
stream.Read(imageIn, 0, imageSize);
using (MemoryStream g = new MemoryStream(imageIn))
{
    g.Position = 0;
    bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(g);
}
```

The actual problem that occurs with the code is that the first time it runs it correctly receives the length and image, however it does not seem to recognize the `\r\n` in consecutive reads, however this may only be a symptom and not the problem itself.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
So I did narrow the problem down and manage to fix it by adding in some artificial delay between my Telnet call using `NetworkStream.Write()` to retrieve the image and the `networkStream.Read()` to retrieve it, however this solution is messy and I would still like to know why this issue is happening

Comment: you are applying `GetString` on an empty array?=! how does that fit into the picture?

Comment: The array isn't actually empty - I'm just adding in a null terminator because that doesn't come in over telnet and I wasn't sure is the `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` added one in. It adds each read value offset by a buffer of a single cycle until I read `\r\n`. I then parse that string to take an integer out of it

Comment: .NET strings don't *really* have a null-terminator (there is a null-byte *after* the string, for interop purposes, but not really part of the string), that's a C thing. .NET strings are length-prefixed. In any case, `Read` returns *up to* the amount of bytes requested. The return value tells you how many bytes were actually read - you need to keep calling it until you get exactly as much data as you need. The way you have it, you only read whatever data managed to arrive at the time, and the rest goes to any subsequent reads - resulting in quite unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The `Read()` operation returns the number of bytes actually read. It only blocks when there is *no* data to read, and it can return less bytes as specified by the `count` parameter.

You can easily fix this by putting this inside a loop:

```
byte[] imageIn = new byte[imageSize];
int remaining = imageSize;
int offset = 0;
while (remaining > 0)
{
    int read = stream.Read(imageIn, offset, remaining);
    if (read == 0) throw new Exception("Connection closed before expected data was read");
    offset += read;
    remaining -= read;
}
```

Comment: The one thing to note is that I am retrieving all the data the first image read (I'm successfully displaying the image in a Windows Forms Picture Box. It's only the data read after the first that appears to be malformed. The image data is also not the part that is not being read correctly but rather the header that includes the image size. I have temporarily fixed the problem by forcing the thread to sleep for a few hundred milliseconds between the read and the `NetworkStream.Write()` call that actually prompts the Telnet server for the image

Comment: Ah I just saw the potential flaw and jumped to the conclusion this would solve your issue. Can you compare what you have received to what you were expecting? I'm wondering if there is a pattern in how the data is malformed, or if it's seemingly random.

Comment: The correct data states just the length of the image in bytes in ASCII. For the current image being taken in the length is 82998 bytes. The length of `len` is 5 (along with some leading zeroes that I filter out, bringing the total length of `len` up to around 8 immediately after reading). The incorrect length of `len` after the first run is between 7500 and 15000 and filled primarily with byte values between 1 and 5 (and a spattering of a few larger values)